# Can this if/else statement be reduced or improved?

Tags: java, if-statement, inline, reduce

I have many classes extending from a base class which has this function:

```
public boolean setVal(int v) {
    if (val != v) {
        val = v;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Since I have so many classes, I would like to make this statement as efficient as possible. I've tried this:

```
public boolean setVal(int v) {
    return val == v ? false : (val = v | true);
}
```

However, I guess I can not change `val` inline like this. (I'm very new to Java)

Can this be made more efficient?

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the best place to ask this sort of question

Comment: "Since I have so many classes, I would like to make this statement as efficient as possible." Do you mean in terms of execution-time efficiency? Do you have any evidence that this is a bottleneck in your application? I'd be quite surprised.

Comment: Here's an alternative approach: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/9d1eb178401811532b4f4ce30f84d26c

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency, worry about correctness.

Comment: Your current way is probably fine, but you could also grab the old value, unconditionally assign, and return the result of comparing them: `int oldVal = val; val = v; return oldVal != v;` That has the advantage of not having an actual branch. But really, unless this is a known bottleneck, write what seems clearest to the reader. This seems **really** unlikely to be where your code will be held up.

Comment: `try { return val != v; } finally { val = v; }` - but that's more of a hack

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Oh that's just evil^H^H^H^H genius^H^H^H^H^H^H evil. :-)

Comment: or just `return val != (val = v);` works since arguments are evaluated from left to right (kind of hard to understand, so not really efficient for programmers to read - I would prefer Jon's suggestion - it describes best what code is expected to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean setVal(int v) {
    return val != (val = v);
}
```

does the following:

1. set `val` to `v`
2. `return` if old value is different than new value

`val` will always be set to `v`, but this is no problem, since if `val` equals `v`, `val` will not have changed.